# Data structure for storing integers and ranges of integers?

Tags: data-structures

Is there an official name for a data structure which is a list of isolated integers and ranges of integers? Besides the obvious "set". One instance of that type would be, for example: "1,3,5,8-10,15,20-30,71,73", where "-" means "all the values in between". I should add that for performance reasons, I don't want to store the isolated points as instances of a Range class I already have. I'm probably going to have a list of isolated points, and a separate list of ranges.

Comment: I'm about to call it "GranularSet", although "set" loses the notion of order, which I want to keep. Maybe "GranularList"?

Answer (score 4):

Note that an isolated integer can be thought of as a range containing just one element; for example, 5 is the range [5, 5].  Given this, what you're describing sounds like it could be modeled with an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), a data structure for storing ranges of values and efficiently querying them.

Hope this helps!